# Change axes label and scale using ggplot and patchwork in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axis-labels, patchwork

(I am trying to make this question as short and concise as possible, as other related answers may be tough for the non-savvy like myself.)

With the following code in mind, is it possible to have both y-axes on the same scale (that of the graph with the highest y-limit), and to have independent labels for each of the axes (namely the y-axes)? I tried to use `facet_wrap` but haven't so far been able to succeed as `Layer 1 is missing`)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
d <- cars
d$Obs <- c(1:50)
f1 <- function(a) {
  ggplot(data=d, aes_string(x="Obs", y=a)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x="Observation",y="Speed/Distance")
}
f1("speed") + f1("dist")
```

[image: Speed and distance graphs using cars]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add two additional arguments to your function, one for the axis label and one for your desired limits.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
d <- cars
d$Obs <- c(1:50)

f1 <- function(a, y_lab) {
  ggplot(data = d, aes_string(x = "Obs", y = a)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = range(c(d$speed, d$dist))) +
    labs(x = "Observation", y = y_lab)
}

f1("speed", "Speed") + f1("dist", "Distance")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Reshape wide-to-long, then use facet. Instead of having different y-axis labels we will have facet labels:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(d, 1:2, names_to = "grp") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Obs, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(vars(grp))
```

[image]